# How can I populate autocomplete by default?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using autocomplete of jquery (not jquery ui autocomplete. I am using it's ancestor). Everything works fine except the autosuggest is only shown when you type something in textbox. My requirements are a bit different. By default I want to show all available suggestions to user. How can I do that?

This is the sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CityAjax").autocomplete(
        "autocomplete_ajax.cfm",
        {
            delay:10,
            minChars:2,
            matchSubset:1,
            matchContains:1,
            cacheLength:10,
            onItemSelect:selectItem,
            onFindValue:findValue,
            formatItem:formatItem,
            autoFill:true
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: show source code of your autocomplete plugin.I think it has minlength check.

Comment: So where is the source? I'm not telepathist...

Comment: @Timu: I posted and corrected. Now please upvote me. Without any reason downvoting doesn't make sense.

Comment: try changing minChars from 2 to 0

Comment: Yes that did the trick. Please post it as answer so I can accept it and upvote. You can also upvote me if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change minChars from 2 to 0. like this

```
$("#CityAjax").autocomplete(
    "autocomplete_ajax.cfm",
    {
        delay:10,
        minChars:0,
        matchSubset:1,
        matchContains:1,
        cacheLength:10,
        onItemSelect:selectItem,
        onFindValue:findValue,
        formatItem:formatItem,
        autoFill:true
    }
);
```